# Showing a list of all unsaved/unknown phone numbers from call log

Tags: android

I want to show a list of all the unknown or unsaved phone numbers from the call log in Android Studio. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you need to point permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

after this - get list and display it

```
context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC")
```

Comment: Will it display all the unsaved phone numbers cuz I only want all the unsaved phone numbers?

Comment: yep. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls